QGIS - Issue with Geometry Disappearing After Merging Attributes in QGIS with SpatiaLite Trigger
I’m working with SpatiaLite, and I have a layer that contains a field named pk, which requires unique values.
However, when using QGIS, there is a tool that allows users to merge attributes from selected entities. When I use this tool, all entities receive the same pk value, which violates the uniqueness constraint. As a result, the database becomes locked, no further changes can be made, all unsaved work is lost, and I have to restart QGIS.
Since this project is intended for users who may not be aware of this behavior, it’s crucial that I prevent this issue to avoid potential data loss.
To address this issue, I added a trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER auto_reassign_pk 
BEFORE UPDATE OF pk ON HABITATS_POLY 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY 
    SET pk = (SELECT MAX(pk) + 1 FROM HABITATS_POLY),
        geom = NEW.geom         --ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsBinary(geom))         --geom
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HABITATS_POLY WHERE pk = NEW.pk); 
    

With this trigger, I no longer encounter issues with duplicate pk values. However, I’m facing a new problem where the geometries behave unexpectedly. After merging, the new geometry disappears from the canvas, though it’s still selectable in the attribute table. Sometimes, the geometry reappears when zooming in or out, depending on the scale, but it cannot be selected from the canvas.


Edit 1:
I chose to use a temporary table to store all the geometries before deleting them from the original layer and reinserting them with a new primary key.
Creation of the temporary table:
CREATE TABLE geom_conflicts (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    original_pk INTEGER,
    geom TEXT,
    lib_phy TEXT
);

To save the geometries on the temporary table:
CREATE TRIGGER handle_pk_conflicts 
BEFORE UPDATE OF pk ON HABITATS_POLY 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HABITATS_POLY WHERE pk = NEW.pk)
BEGIN 
    -- Stocker les géométries en conflit dans la table temporaire
    INSERT INTO geom_conflicts (original_pk, geom, lib_phy)
    SELECT pk, ST_AsText(geom), lib_physio
    FROM HABITATS_POLY
    WHERE pk = NEW.pk;

    INSERT INTO geom_conflicts (original_pk, geom, lib_phy)
    SELECT NEW.pk, ST_AsText(geom), NEW.lib_physio
    FROM HABITATS_POLY
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid OR pk = NEW.pk;
    
    -- Supprimer l'entité en conflit de la table principale
    DELETE FROM HABITATS_POLY
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;        -- OR pk = NEW.pk;
END;

I had to repeat the insert operation to manage both pk and new.pk, otherwise, I wasn't capturing all the geometries.
To reinsert geometries from the temporary table:
CREATE TRIGGER reinsert_conflicted_geometries
AFTER INSERT ON geom_conflicts
BEGIN
    -- Insérer la géométrie dans la table principale avec un nouveau PK
    INSERT INTO HABITATS_POLY (geom, lib_physio)
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText(geom, 2154), lib_phy
    FROM geom_conflicts
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
    
    -- Nettoyer la table temporaire
  --  DELETE FROM geom_conflicts
   -- WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;

However, I'm still facing an issue: the last updated entity is not being properly inserted into HABITATS_POLY, so it disappears again.
All entities are being saved in geom_conflicts, but it seems that the geometry (geom) of the last one isn't being stored correctly. Even when I try to insert it manually:
INSERT INTO HABITATS_POLY (geom, lib_physio)
SELECT ST_multi(geom), lib_phy 
FROM geom_conflicts 
WHERE id = 9;

The insertion doesn't add the polygon.

This could be because of an corrupt spatial index or geometries. Is the behaviour the same after runnig UPDATE HABITATS_POLY SET geom = ST_Buffer(geom, 0) to recreate the geometries?

I tried ST_Buffer and several spatial operations, it didn't resolve the issue.

So finally, here is how I resolved my issue :
Create à temporary table:
CREATE TABLE geom_conflicts (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    original_pk INTEGER,
    geom TEXT,
    lib_phy TEXT,
    new_pk INTEGER
    cat_conf TEXT
);

I save the information of the duplicated pk in the temporary table :
CREATE TRIGGER handle_pk_conflicts_hp
BEFORE UPDATE OF pk ON HABITATS_POLY 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO geom_conflicts (original_pk, geom, lib_phy, new_pk, cat_conf)
    SELECT 
        OLD.pk, 
        ST_AsText(OLD.geom), 
        COALESCE(NEW.lib_physio, OLD.lib_physio),
        NEW.pk, 
        'Habitats'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM geom_conflicts 
        WHERE geom = ST_AsText(OLD.geom) 
          AND (original_pk = OLD.pk OR new_pk = NEW.pk)
    );
END;

I delete polygons with duplicated pk and I reinsert them using the temporary table:
CREATE TRIGGER reinsert_conflicted_geometries
AFTER INSERT ON geom_conflicts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM HABITATS_POLY
WHERE NEW.cat_conf = 'Habitats'
    AND pk = NEW.new_pk;                    

INSERT INTO HABITATS_POLY (geom, lib_physio)
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(geom, 2154), lib_phy
FROM geom_conflicts
WHERE NEW.cat_conf = 'Habitats'
    AND id = NEW.id;

